# Is it possible to change the color of a nested list when hovered over?

Tags: list, css, nested

I created a CSS only navigation and I am trying to figure out if it is possible to change the color of the text in a nested list when hovered over.

```
        <div id="navigation">
    <ul class="top-level">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Residential</a>
            <ul class="sub-level">
                <li><a href="#">Project 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Project 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Project 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Project 4</a></li>
            </ul>
```

So as it is when I hover over 'Residential', "Project 1 - 4" appears and I have managed to make the text a different color and background than 'Residential'. However, what I would like to do is now change the color of the text in 'Project 1-4' when hovered over. Is that possible in CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You may use **[CSS Pseudo-classes](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp)** to achieve this.

`.elementclass:hover` can be used to style the element on hover.

Comment: I did a second time after you suggested it and no luck.

Comment: create a demo at jsfiddle.net , save it, and post the link

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...
I was pretty certain I already try this but maybe for some reason it didn't update. Apparently under the class below I needed to add white and then I needed to make sure the proceeding class below also had the color black(which it did). BlasterAlfred I have to give you some credit as well.

```
#navigation a:hover{
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
}

#navigation li li a {
color: black;
}
```